# How can I make sure ajax/jquery calls finish before an html page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```
$(function() {
    var $items = $('#items');
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'some-url',
      data: {},
      success: function(items) {
        $.each(items, function(i, item){
          item_polys.push(item.polygon);
          $items.append(`<a href="somepage.html" onclick="localStorage.setItem('item', '${item.item_id}'); localStorage.setItem('item_poly', '${item.polygon}')";>${item.item_id}</a>`);
        });
        localStorage.setItem('item_polys', JSON.stringify(item_polys));
      },
      // Error handling 
      error: function (error) {
          console.log(`Error ${error}`);
      },
});
```

I need 'item_polys' to be saved into local storage *before* my corresponding html page loads. I would also settle for a way to reload the html page just one time each time after it loads, so that it will populate correctly. Thanks (and sorry if this has been answered already, I couldn't quite find what I was looking for when I searched)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the ajax request to occur when the user is on the exact same page that the populated elements will be in, I think the only *good* way of doing this would be to create or display the elements of the page dynamically. (This might be as simple as toggling a `display: none` on and off, but it depends on what the page is like and what you want.)

So, make a function like `populatePage` that shows the page, where the default state of the page is a loading screen (or blank, or whatever you want the user to see when the request is in progress). Maybe something like

```
const populatePage = () => {
  const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.items);
  for (const item of items) {
    $items.append(`<a href="somepage.html" onclick="localStorage.setItem('item', '${item.item_id}'); localStorage.setItem('item_poly', '${item.polygon}')";>${item.item_id}</a>`);
  }
  $('main').show();
};
```

where `main` is the container you want to show when things are ready, and that has styling that hides it by default. Then:

On pageload, check if the item exists in storage. If so, use it, and call `populatePage` immediately. Otherwise, have the page keep showing the loading banner or blank screen, make the ajax request, and call `populatePage` when it's finished.

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  success: function (items) {
    localStorage.items = JSON.stringify(items);
    populatePage();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon as I can. Drop a couple upvotes if you can, I am only 2 away from enough rep to vote. I will upvote back when I make it

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot was searching just like this.